# Scale-able plotting of data stream from Elasticsearch

Tags: python, pandas, plot, elasticsearch, bigdata

Assume that I have a set of documents stored in an index of Elasticsearch, such that each document has the following (simplified) form:

```
{
  "timestamp": N,
  "val": X
}
```

where `N` is a long integer representing a unix-timestamp and `X` is some float.

My goal is to plot the behavior of `val` over time; in other words, obtain a graph where the x-axis is the time(stamp) and the y-axis is the `val`.

### Medium-Small number of document

If the number of documents stored in the index is medium-small, then using `python` I could do the following. Scan the documents, using for example the [scan-helper](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.scan), and create a list of the JSON documents. Next, convert the list into a `pandas.DataFrame` and sort its line according to the `timestamp`. Finally, I can, now easily, plot the data as I described above. Here is a minimal example:

```
docs = scan(
            es, # instance of es-client
            index = 'myIndex',
            doc_type = 'myDocType')
docsList = []
for doc in docs:
    docsList.append(doc)
dfDocs = pandas.DataFrame(docsList)
dfDocsSorted = dfDocs.sort(columns='timestamp')
dfDocsSorted.plot(x='timestamp', y='val')
```

Here is how the output looks like for some sample data set:

[image]

I find it a rather clean and fine solution, given the number of documents is limited.

### Large number of documents

What is the "right" way to do the same as above in the case where the number of documents is *large*? Note that the sorting step above is rather mandatory, as far as I can tell, since the `scan` returns documents in a "random" order. Therefore, if the number of documents is large, this step (and the storing of the data) will become an issue.

Is there a canonical way to achieve this using Elasticsearch? Or am I bound to carry out a pre-processing locally before being able to plot the data?

Comment: Did you find a answer for this?

Comment: I'm not sure any more...